# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect STATUS:400

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring bind property to submit Data into Database.
I have used a button on click on this action part is:

```
/something/submit
```

And For this I have used request mapping

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/something/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Everything is working fine. Data is fetched and shown but when i add new entity with this action event this gives this error.

Comment: It looks to me like the HTTP request has a syntax error.

Comment: @chrylis: can u tell what syntax error you can see.

Comment: @kushal: please post some stack trace. "It gives error", such statement cannot help others to tell you what exactly error is.

Comment: There was no syntax error. I got solution. I was having signature problem in spring format.